# Date increment in excel vba during transition to new month

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
 Private Sub newMonth(MonthValue As Date)
'month value is the value that is passed into it from the first data row of the old sheet

Dim isWeekend As Boolean

Dim i As Long

'is it a year shift? (december = 12, january = 1)
If Month(MonthValue) + 1 < Month(MonthValue) Then
    For i = 0 To 4
        'is the date at least 5 days in the week from sunday?

        If Weekday(Format(DateSerial(Year(MonthValue) + 1, Month(MonthValue) + 1, i + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy"), vbSunday) > 5 Then
            'put in the cells of the new sheet in the first column a date starting from the first day of the next month
            Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW + (i * 2), 1) = Format(DateSerial(Year(MonthValue) + 1, Month(MonthValue) + 1, i + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Else
            'if its not, clear contents
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW + (i * 2), 1), Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW + (i * 2), 32)).ClearContents

        End If



    Next i
'it is not a year shift, just an increment of a month
Else

   for i = 0 to 4
         If Weekday(Format(DateSerial(Year(MonthValue), Month(MonthValue) + 1, i + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy"), vbSunday) > 1 And _
            Weekday(Format(DateSerial(Year(MonthValue), Month(MonthValue) + 1, i + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy"), vbSunday) < 7 Then
            'put in the cells of the new sheet in the first column a date starting from the first day of the next month
            Cells(7 + (i * 2), 1) = Format(DateSerial(Year(MonthValue), Month(MonthValue) + 1, i + 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
           i = i + 1
        Else
            'if its not, clear contents
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW + (i * 2), 1), Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW + (i * 2), 32)).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End If


End Sub
```

Greetings. The above code has two worksheets of relevance, I'll call them worksheet A and worksheet B. It is part of an overall time/attendance tracking system, and makes a new sheet for each period. So for instance, sheet A will have dates 8/6 - 8/10, and sheet B will have dates 8/13-8/17. Weekends are not covered in the sheets; only workdays.

The following function is called when it is not just a change of weeks but also a change of months. So for instance if sheet A had 7/30-7/31 (monday and tuesday of last week), sheet B should have 8/1-8/3 (wednesday through friday of last week.

The trouble is that regardless, the first date on sheet B should appear in cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, 1)  By the way, FIRST_DATA_ROW = 7. This runs into problem if for instance, sheet A finishes on a Tuesday, because the way that the code is written will have the first date appear in cells(11,1) because. In other words, I need cells (7, 1) to be the monday of the new week, cells(9, 1) to be the tuesday of the new week, etc; unless the previous week ended on a Tuesday, in which case I need cells(7,1) to be the Wednesday of the new week, cells(9, 1) to be the thursday of the new week, and  cells (11,1) to be the friday of the new week, and for the code to terminate after this because the next value is a weekend.

Comment: `Month(MonthValue)` will return a value in range 1 to 12. `Month(MonthValue) + 1` will be a value in range 2 to 13. not a lot of chances for `Month(MonthValue) + 1 < Month(MonthValue)`

Comment: That's why I have the ELSE statement at the bottom. The above if statement is for when the month of sheet A is december (12) and the month of sheet B is january (1)

Comment: Your comparison does not reference neither sheet A nor B, `MonthValue` has no reason to change, the test will **always** be false.

Comment: BTW, there is no references to sheet A or sheet B anywhere in your code, the code will always apply to the current ActiveSheet.

Comment: Is your above code complete? I see it only working with one sheet, inserting from `Date` to `Date +4 days` in the specified range. If you want to use two sheets you'll need to make a if inside your loop, check if it's a new month and tell Excel where is your range in your other sheet.